# Java code problem: search and replace

Tags: java, search, replace

Have a question: how can I in Java find all the words in the texts that are, for example 4 symbols long? and then how can I replace them?

for finding some piece of text I wrote

<

```
fButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{int i=text.getText().indexOf(field2.getText(),text.getSelectionStart());
if(i>=0)
text.select(i,i+field2.getText().length());
text.requestFocusInWindow()
```

;>

I tried to combine buttons and fields, but all I have are 2 errors:

```
symbol  : method parseInt (javax.swing.JTextField)
location: class java.lang.Integer
numb=Integer.parseInt(field2);
            ^
symbol  : method replaceAll (java.lang.String,javax.swing.JTextField)
location: class javax.swing.JTextArea
text = text.replaceAll("\\b\\w{4}\\b", field3);
           ^
```

code:

```
 field2=new JTextField("Enter number",10);
    int numb;
    numb=Integer.parseInt(field2);
    tPanel.add(field2);
    JButton fButton=new JButton ("Find and Replace");
    tPanel.add(fButton);
    fButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
    text = text.replaceAll("\\b\\w{4}\\b", field3);
    }});
    field3=new JTextField("Enter replace",10);
    tPanel.add(field3);
```

Cant understand it(((

Answer (score 4):

You wrote "symbols" in your question. I will intepreat that as "word characters". If you would like another definition look at the [regular expression summary in the `Pattern` api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Use [`String.replaceAll(regularExpression, replacementText)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and the regular expression to use is `"\b\w{4}\b"`.

- `\b` is "word boundary"
- `\w` is "word characters"
- `{4}` is how many of the "before" symbols to match (in this case word characters)

So to replace all 4-letter words in a string `text` do (note that all `\`'s are escaped by another `\`):

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\b\\w{4}\\b", "replaced");
```

For example:

```
System.out.println("bla blaa hello test".replaceAll("\\b\\w{4}\\b", "mupp"));
```

Outputs:

```
bla mupp hello mupp
```

---

### To answer your updated question:

Code below produced this screeshot:

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JTextArea area = new JTextArea("bla blaa hello test");
    final JTextField numberField  = new JTextField("4", 10);
    final JTextField replaceField = new JTextField("muff", 10);

    JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Replace") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String text = area.getText();
            int    syms = Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText());
            String repl = replaceField.getText();

            area.setText(text.replaceAll("\\b\\w{"+syms+"}\\b", repl));
        }
    });

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(numberField);
    panel.add(replaceField);
    panel.add(button);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: OK... I tried to combine them with adding buttons and fields and thats what I got: field2=new JTextField("Enter your number",10);
int numb;
numb=Integer.parseInt(field2);
tPanel.add(field2);
JButton fButton=new JButton ("Find and Replace");
tPanel.add(fButton);
fButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{text = text.replaceAll("\\b\\w{4}\\b", field3);
}});
field3=new JTextField("Enter your sentence",10);
tPanel.add(field3);